# FB API v5 CSRF issue : token session is modified

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-php-sdk

After a long time to look for a solution to my problem, I don't succeed to solve it.
So, I have this error : Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

I know it is because token in Session and in URL are not the same. After several tests, I found that token in sesssion ($_SESSION['FBRLH_state']) is modified between my first PHP file in which I call getLoginUrl() and my second PHP file callback (fb_callback.php). So, obviously, because token changed, it can be same that in the URL.
I verified that in my callback file, getLoginUrl is not called, so in the process this function is called just one time.
A schema to be sure you understand me :
Login.php :

```
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook($config);
$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_likes'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.marche-prive.com/fb_callback.php', $permissions);
```

After this, FBRLH_state equal to a value A.

fb_callback.php :

```
//FBRLH_state equals B
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook($config);
$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_likes'];
```

Do you know why my token session is modified between these 2 files ?

Thanks

Comment: have the same problem! but the weird thing it happens only on mobile browser... if i put $_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state']; before the callback code it bpas the csrf security, but this is risky, and can't figure why this is happening, and wh the hell only on mobile!!! on desktop it's fine...

Comment: This happens to me also, but only on the first request within Chrome, Firefox, or Safari. Subsequent requests don't have an issue. Very strange!